# 1364 Field 'schedule_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel-5

Schedule_id field not found

//controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

    $schedule = new menu;
    $days = new day;
    $schedule->scheduleName = $request->name;
    $schedule->sensor = $request->sensor;
    $schedule->start_time = $request->start_time;
    $schedule->end_time = $request->end_time;
    $schedule->timestamps = false;
    $schedule->s_daytime = $request->s_daytime;
    $schedule->e_daytime = $request->e_daytime;
    $days->days = $request->days;
    $days->timestamps = false;
    $days->save();
    $schedule->save();




    return view('store');

}
```

// Model

```
class menu extends Model
{
    protected $table = "schedule";

    protected $fillable = [
    'scheduleName', 'start_time', 'end_time','sensor','s_daytime','e_daytime',

    ];
    public function days()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\day');
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your table `day(s)` has a `schedule_id` column?

Comment: Yes it have schedule column

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there's no where you define that your record `menu` is the parent of `day` when you creating them

Here how you can do

```php
$schedule = new menu;
$schedule->scheduleName = $request->name;
$schedule->sensor = $request->sensor;
$schedule->start_time = $request->start_time;
$schedule->end_time = $request->end_time;
$schedule->timestamps = false;
$schedule->s_daytime = $request->s_daytime;
$schedule->e_daytime = $request->e_daytime;
$schedule->save();

// First alternative
$day = $schedule->days()->create([
    'days' => $request->days,
    'timestamps' => false, // not sure if it's an attribute in your case
]);

// Second alternative
$day = new day;
$days->days = $request->days;
$days->schedule_id = $schedule->id; // notice this line
$days->timestamps = false;
$days->save();
```

Also I believe that your relationship `days` should be, but I may be wrong since you have set the database name to `schedule`

```php
public function days()
{
    // By default, Laravel will expect `menu_id`
    return $this->hasMany('App\day', 'schedule_id');
}
```

---

tips (1): if `$timestamps` is the public attribute and it's always false, you better set it in your Model.

tips (2): Assuming you did the tips (1), you can reduce the number of lines like this

```php
$schedule = menu::create($request->only(
        'name', 'sensor', 'start_time', 'end_time', 's_daytime', 'e_daytime'
    ));

$day = $schedule->days()->create($request->only(
        'days'
    ));
```